# In ObjC, which of the following is not an object? NSObject, NSStringLiteral, NSInteger, NSValue?

Tags: objective-c

```
NSInteger nine = 9;
float ten = 10.0;

NSNumber *nineFromInteger = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInteger:nine];
NSNumber *tenFromFloat = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:ten];
```

Comment: Everything without an asterisk between type and variable name is not an object

Comment: @vadian - But everything *with* an asterisk between type and variable name is not an object either.

Comment: in the question `nine` and `ten` aren't objects, `nineFromInteger` and `tenFromFloat` are objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be advised to go through [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/index.html) for data types. For your quick reference here is my answer for this:

**NSInteger** - A primitive data type. **Not a class, so cannot create object**. Never use * (pointer) to access it.

**float** - A primitive data type. **Not a class, so cannot create object**. Never use * (pointer) to access it.

**NSNumber** - A subclass of NSValue. **Since a class, can create object**. Always use * (pointer) to access it.

**NSObject** - Root class of most Objective-C class hierarchies.  **Since a class, can create object**.

Comment: `NSInteger *` and `float *` are perfectly valid types, `*`'s are used with primitive types. Most code does not "use *" to access an `NSNumber` instance, the `*` occurs in the *declaration* of a variable. Also consider `id`. You might wish to make this answer clearer.